# Como funciona o JUnit?

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, junit

Como funciona o framework open-source JUnit? Ele garante o aumento da qualidade do software? É recomendável escrever testes unitários no dia a dia?

Comment: Alterei a indagação final pra que não pareça que a pergunta é opinativa e seja fechada. Caso ache que possa ser melhorado, pode editar sem problemas  :)

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### como funciona o framework JUnit

No trabalho, usamos o JUnit para garantir o resultado do nosso sistema. A qualquer momento, mandamos a IDE realizar os testes automáticos para saber se tem algo fora do esperado.

### ele garante aumento na qualidade?

Por si só, não. Ele pode ser usado para TDD (desenvolvimento direcionado a testes) e também como garantia para detectar regressão de software (regressão: algo funcionava antes mas não funciona mais).

A garantia dos testes dependem muito mais do designer de teste do que só JUnit em si. Se o teste for mal programado, JUnit não fará milagres. Possivelmente sua existência seja pior para o desenvolvimento do que se os testes não existissem.

### no dia a dia, você recomenda a escrita de testes unitários?

SIIIIM!!!!! Com todas as forças! Desenvolva usando método TDD e terá muito menos dor de cabeça. Sem falar que você poderá testar a lógica pura de seu programa, sem UI.

Essa dica de testar sem UI é especialmente importante para testes em que a interação com a UI é longa até chegar no trecho desejado ou se subir a UI for traumático. (Exemplo de subir UI traumático: projetos GWT mal estruturados, pode demorar mais de 40 minutos para subir o servidor, para só então começar a testar).

Answer (score 1):

> Como funciona o framework open-source JUnit?

O framework JUnit serve para verificar se o que está sendo produzido funciona corretamente. Normalmente a maioria dos bugs não são por erro de sintaxe, mas por problemas nas validações de saída ( Quem nunca pois um 'else' a mais no 'if-else'?). Então o framework vai verificar a saida correta. Nele você vai montar o cenário e verificar sua saída (normalmente usa-se o assertEquals).

> Ele garante o aumento da qualidade do software?

Ele por si só não garante o aumento da qualidade, mas se você usar algumas técnicas simples, como partição de equivalência e verificar os valores limite (a>0 && a<10), dentre outras, você vai achar bugs mais facilmente.
Fora os testes de regressão(refazer o mesmo teste para ver se não quebrou nada).

> É recomendável escrever testes unitários no dia a dia?

É tão recomendável que existe até métodos como TDD e o BDD, que a base é essa: Você fazer código de testes unitários todos os dias, antes do seu código.

Tem um trecho no livro do Mauricio Anchine(Testes de Software) que faz a seguinte pergunta: "Se eu escrever testes de unidade antes do meu código eu serei produtivo?"

O autor responde da seguinte maneira: Se ser mais produtivo significa mais código, não. Mas se você fala de qualidade de código e retrabalho, você será muito mais produtivo.

Espero ter ajudado

Referências:

https://www.devmedia.com.br/junit-tutorial/1432

https://www.casadocodigo.com.br/products/livro-testes-de-software

https://blog.locaweb.com.br/desenvolvedores/entenda-o-que-e-tdd-e-quais-sao-as-suas-vantagens/